# E-mail getting rejected sent by Nodemailer

Tags: node.js, express, nodemailer

[image]I am trying to send an email which includes HTML content with the help of nodemailer-express-handlebars. Every time my mail gets blocked by the Gmail which can be checked in sender's Gmail sent-box whereas I got success msg from nodemailer
`Email sent: 250 2.0.0 OK  1595608108 i66sm6757247pfc.12 - gsmtp`
I am unable to understand why this happening as when I send a mail with text, it gets delivered.

***NODEMAILER CODE***

```
sendMail=(email)=>{
    var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
          user: 'emailId',
          pass: 'password'
        }
      });

      transporter.use('compile',hbs({
          viewEngine:{
            partialsDir:"./views/",
            defaultLayout: "",
            layoutsDir: "",
          },
          viewPath:"./views/",
          extName:'.hbs',
      }))
      var mailOptions = {
        from: '<xyz@gmail.com>',
        to: email,
        subject: 'Your order has been placed successfully.',
        template:'mail',
        context:{
            name:"XYZ",
            address:"133"
        }
 
      };
      
      transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
        } else {
          console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
        }
      });
}
```

Comment: Have you given the required permission to gmail?

Comment: Yes, text mail can be sent and received by the receiver but unable to send html

Comment: Are you sending this from localhost?

Comment: Currently using localhost. Is it something to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

It's [recommended](https://nodemailer.com/usage/using-gmail/) to use OAuth2 with NodeMailer and Gmail.  Using the plain username and password might be what's causing you problems.